# Why is iBooks progress incorrect in my Siri Suggestions, and how is this fixed?

Tags: ipad, books, siri

[image: Siri Suggestions Screenshot]

In this case, Siri Suggestions implies that I have just started the book. I've actually been reading it for weeks and am on page 685/1985. Clicking the Siri Suggestion for the book brings me to the correct page. This is on iOS 9.1 (13B143).

[image: iBooks Screenshot]

Comment: Mine's showing *Finished*. It's fixed when I restarted my iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings>General>Spotlight Search. Turn off and on Siri Suggestions. It worked for me.